# Is there a way to upload a image with AJAX after clicking on the picture that immediatly changes the source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

I'm currently working on a project with ASP.net/Razor. In this project i have a profile image. My goal is to get an image from my computer uploaded to the server so i can refresh the old picture with the new 1 after i clicked on the old image and selected a new one on my computer(as most websites do look at twitter, facebook and linkedin). I haven't found a way how to though and i'm quite noob so i hope somebody can help me with this :). i was thinking with a onclick event in an ajax call that changes the picture but suggestions are ofc welcome :)

thanks in advance,  
Marijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do achieve this, you will have to save the content of the file (binary) somewhere (probably DB). If you want to display what the profile will look like before saving the image, do the following :

1 - Upload the image to the server.

2 - Save the image temporay on the server (put it in session).

3 - Get the binary to the client and put it in the src of the image.

4 - When user save, Save the image somewhere. Binary in the DB or file on file system.

Comment: this is helpfull do you happen to have a tutorial with some information to explain to me? i think i got the basics but

Comment: qeustion most of all really is how do you open windows explorer from an ajax call...